# IIS7.5 Direct all requests to one page

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I wish to create a site that returns the same html page for all page requests.

For example the same page will be served for all the below requests:

```
http://holdingsite
http://holdingsite/foo
http://holdingsite/foo/bar
http://holdingsite/foo.aspx
http://holdingsite/foo.html
```

What configuration is needed to ensure every request is directed to this one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, install the [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

You can then add a rewrite rule to you config

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="catchall" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url=".*" />
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="/somepage.htm" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

N.b You can also configure this via IIS once you have installed the module